# Using an interactive interpreter as makeprg

Tags: makeprg

Is there any way to use an interactive interpreter as the `makeprg`? I want the interpreter to stay interactive after invoking `:make`.

For example, if I wanted to invoke python on the current file and stay in interactive mode, I would imagine that `:set makeprg=python\ -i\ %` would do what I wanted, the `-i` argument telling python to stay in interactive mode after running a script. However if I run a small python script like this vim just prints out the python command prompt (`>>>`) and then returns me to the editor.

Comment: I am not sure `:make` is going to be the proper fit here. Have you thought about using `:terminal` (NeoVim and Vim 8)?

Comment: ah, nice. I'm in neovim and `:terminal python -i %` does what I want.

Comment: well, kind of. Still trying to compose it with the behavior of `:make`. In effect I want to run `:make`, and if the make command succeeds, run `:terminal python -i %`. If `:make` does not succeed, do the normal make behavior (quickfix list etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `:make` to lint and then run `:terminal` if there are no errors.

```
command! -nargs=* -bang -complete=file_in_path PythonMake call <SID>PythonMake("<bang>", <q-args>)
function! s:PythonMake(bang, args)
    execute 'make' . a:bang . ' ' . a:args
    if empty(filter(getqflist(), 'v:val.valid'))
        execute 'terminal python -i %'
    endif
endfunction
```

Note: I have not tested this code in any way nor do I use NeoVim.

The idea is to use `:make` then check for any valid errors (`valid` key) which is returned by `getqflist()`. If no errors then run your `:terminal` command with the current buffer's filename, `%`.

For more help see:

```
:h :command
:h :make
:h getqflist()
:h filter()
:h empty()
:h :terminal
```